# file statement vs. filename assignment in sas

Tags: sas

I thought the following two data steps would be equivalent, but in a UNIX environment they produce slightly different binary files. Can anyone explain why?

```
/*Example 1*/
filename myfile "/tmp/file1";

data _null_;
file myfile recfm=n;
a=1;
put a;
run;

filename myfile;

/*Example 2*/
data _null_;
file "/tmp/file2" recfm=n;
a=1;
put a;
run;
```

Comment: I don't see a difference when using your example.  Perhaps you actually ran something else?  Is it possible some other process is changing those files in the /tmp/ directory?

Comment: Slightly different? How different?

Comment: Will update with better reproduction steps when I have them.

Comment: You will probably find that your actual code uses different PUT statement options implied or explicit that cause the difference.  For example, PUT A; uses LIST-PUT and prints a space after the value 1.